# Nuxt/Buefy - <client-only> component shows inconsinstently

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, bulma, buefy

I have a really weird issue in my Nuxt/Buefy project. I have a component, `site-header`, which loads a child component, `user-location` for client-side only use, like so:

**components/site-header.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div class=header-wrapper>
    <div class=container>
      <b-navbar centered class=navbar>
        <template #end>
          <nav-link v-for='(obj, token) in $store.state.siteNav' :navItemObj=obj :key=token :id=token />
          <client-only>
            <user-location usage=siteHeader />
          </client-only>
        </template>
      </b-navbar>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

The problem I've got is `user-location` shows momentarily on hot reload, but **never shows when I load/refresh the page**.

However, if I move it outside of `b-navbar`, it shows every time.

```html
<template>
  <div class=header-wrapper>
    <div class=container>
    <nav-link v-for='(obj, token) in $store.state.siteNav' :navItemObj=obj :key=token :id=token />
    <client-only>
      <user-location usage=siteHeader />
      </client-only>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

What could account for this? One thing which may or may not be related: this was working fine until I deleted my `node_modules` dir to reinstall everything.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I did noticed some issues like this too on some of my projects.
I'd say that this issue is mainly coming from HMR not being able to detect that we don't really need it and still injects it inside of your template or maybe the fact that Webpack's bundle is huge in your project.
At least, this bug never happens on production so it should be okay!

Either ways, Nuxt v3 will soon be released and it will be available with Vite, so I'm not sure that we will have those issues anymore looking on the way it works.

Othwerwise, you could maybe dive deep in the configuration of HMR and make some conditional to see if some (nested) block was updated in `<client-only>`.
There is meanwhile probably no quick and simple way of fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

If its **SSR**, then there are multiple causes it shows black page.

One of the reason is `elements` are not closed properly. So try to close them in proper manner.

Do this:

```html
<user-location usage="siteHeader"></user-location> // also, added quotes to "siteHeader" - Usually it should be there
```

Instead of :

```html
<user-location usage="siteHeader" />
```

This might fix the issue :)

Comment: Yep, ESlint can be useful!

Comment: @kissu Do you mean, Eslint can auto fix closing tags in this way?

Comment: Are you saying Nuxt/Vue don't like self-closing components? I've not had any other problems with this - indeed, the problem I wrote about only started after I reran `npm install`; it worked fine before.

Comment: This answer is not helpful if are not facing problem with blank page on refresh and content is SSR.

Comment: ESlint can help you spot the errors and Prettier can help you see it more easily visually yep! @Mitya here is the documentation related on how to properly write components https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Self-closing-components-strongly-recommended If you have issues with NPM, be sure that you don't have a `yarn.lock` in your project, also don't hesitate to wipe your `node_modules`, clean the NPM cache and install it from scratch. (this was never the issue for me tbh)